# Make KDE use max resolution available for second monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, resolution, kde, udev

KDE user, Thinkpad T450s.

I have a second monitor at home, and another one in my office. When I plug in any of the two in my VGA port, the system automatically assigns to it a 1024x768 resolution.

How do I make KDE automatically use the maximum resolution available?

Ideally, I would like the system to launch:

```
xrandr --output DP2 --auto --right-of eDP1
```

I tried writing a `udev` rule, but without success (the script works, but is not launched, or at least not successfully). I'm a noob, so I'm not sure I did everything right with `udev`. But isn't there a simpler solution? Is there a line I should change somewhere to make KDE choose the max resolution instead?

(Alternatively, can you tell me how to write the udev rule, and how to use it?)

Thanks!

PS I need a solution that works for all users!